# Google map API Key request failed [Elementor]

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3, elementor

I'm using elementor to build website for a friend. Using google map feature to display the current location of her hostel.

Created google map api key and set it up in elementor settings.
Looks like elementor is sending request with another key rather using the one I set up.

Already spoke with google map support and the issu comes from elementor sending request with another key, so that any attempt to set up a key myself is effortless.

Can't figure out where and how to make appropriate changes so that it work properly.

Somebody faced the same issue ?

Tried to create multiple project with new api keys

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: I have the same issue, clearing cache does not resolve. 

 @Emeric did you manage to solve this issue? If so how?